# Sticky column header doesn't stay fixed

Tags: html, css, css-tables, bootstrap-5

I'm attempting to keep the first column in my table entirely fixed on mobile devices, so when a user tries to scroll through the data, they are able to see who exactly they are viewing. So far, the td elements for the table are perfect and react as how I want it, but the column header is still being scrolled and not staying in its true position.

Table before scroll:

[image: Table before scroll]

Table after scroll:

[image: Table after scroll]

Here is the CSS that controls the devices with widths less than 600px:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {

    th {
        overflow: auto;
    }


    .first {
        position: fixed;
        width: 90px;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .firsth {
        position: sticky;
        width: 90px;
        z-index: 2;
    }

}
```

The codepen is a bit weird as it doesn't contain the original styles, but nevertheless, I have provided it to make the task a bit easier to understand.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/AssistSyed/pen/mdmYVvv)

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
.firsth {
    position: sticky;
    width: 90px;
    z-index: 2;
    top:90px;
    }
```

**sticky wont work unles you specify where to stick you need to specify it like top:90; this should work.**